# Linker error with Libtorch, Cmake and CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch, clion, libtorch

I am just starting out with libtorch and seem to have run into a rather serious linker issue. Previously, I was able to at least build other projects with torch (that others had created), but now that I've tried to create my own simple file, nothing seems to be building anymore.

I have manually installed the latest MacOS build in my root directory:
/Users/jlenz/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch

I am using CLion and have the following CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(midi_plugin)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(midi_plugin main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "~/libtorch/share/cmake")
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(midi_plugin "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
```

One thing that is noticeable, although the cmake 'succesfully' builds, it displays this in the process:

```
-- MKL_ARCH: intel64
-- MKL_ROOT /Users/jlenz/opt/miniconda3
-- MKL_LINK: dynamic
-- MKL_INTERFACE_FULL: intel_ilp64
-- MKL_THREADING: intel_thread
-- MKL_MPI: mpich
```

Once I try to build the project (which is just 'hello world' with torch included) I get the following error:

```
FAILED: midi_plugin 
: && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=12.5 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/midi_plugin.dir/main.cpp.o -o midi_plugin  -Wl,-rpath,/Users/jlenz/libtorch/lib  /Users/jlenz/libtorch/lib/libc10.dylib  /Users/jlenz/libtorch/lib/libkineto.a  /Users/jlenz/libtorch/lib/libtorch.dylib  /Users/jlenz/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib  /Users/jlenz/libtorch/lib/libc10.dylib  -lmkl_intel_ilp64  -lmkl_core  -lmkl_intel_thread && :
ld: library not found for -lmkl_intel_ilp64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Would anyone know how to solve this? I have tried addressing it with a colleague who has used libtorch quite a bit and he can't identify the issue either. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're going to use the MKL from miniconda, you should use the libtorch from miniconda, too.

Comment: If MKL is an optional dependency for PyTorch, you can set `-DCMAKE_DISABLE_FIND_PACKAGE_MKL=ON` at the CMake configure command line. Start from a clean build directory if you do this.

Comment: @AlexReinking in my cmake script I never specify where to find MKL and in my colleagues this is also the case. Any idea why it is looking there (instead of my torch directory)? Or if I need it at all?

Comment: The torch package is looking for MKL as a dependency. I don't know if your build of torch needs it absolutely or if it is looking for it as an optional feature.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my solution here in case someone else runs into a similar issue.
It turns out the issue was with my brew installation of torch, which was being referenced implicitly. To fix it, all I had to do was:

Brew install pytorch

It asked permission to overwrite some files that had issues, which I granted. Afterwards, all of my Torch projects are working perfectly.